# Symfony2 FosUser Register e-mail

Tags: database, symfony, email, registration, fosuserbundle

I moved my website in Symfony2 to another web server.
In the first email I received the registration and to change passwords.
In the latter rather I not get more.
What can be?

I can not figure out if it's a problem of parameters or more, partly because the controller code in the registration have not touched it ..
It states that in this web server use as DB HeidiSQL and not more phpMyAdmin ..

I use FosUserBundle

The code is equal ... How can i do??

Comment: Did you check you can correctly send emails from the second web site ? Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: Yes i clear the cache,  i don t know if i can send emails from the second web site because I have to ask systems engineer.. I don t know..

Comment: check in app/parameters.yml your mail settings.